# Excel rounddown function equivalent in php

Tags: php

Everyday we need to calculate number of units allocated based on two variables called investment amount and NAV. This we are doing now in Excel using rounddown function, which I am trying to achieve in PHP but it is sometimes rounding up the result.

```
In Excel:
Cell A1 = 287011570.56
Cell B1 = 14.9482
Cell C1 = =ROUNDDOWN(A1/ROUND(B1,4),4)
       = 19200410.1202

In PHP:
<?php
$var1=287011570.56;
$var2=14.9482;
$var3=$var1/$var2;
$var4 = floor(($var3) * 100000 + .5) * .00001;
$var5 = intval($var4);
$var6 = strlen($var5)+5;
$test = substr("$var4", 0, $var6);
print "$test";
?>
```

Result : 19200410.1203

The result should contain 4 digits after decimal and it should not round up the result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP does not have a built-in floating point type that can guarantee that much precision ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)), so you should definitely decide how important the precision is to you. Also, since PHP's builtin floats are definitely IEEE 754 they are also not as accurate as they are precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to add the 0.5 when you are using `floor()`.  That can move the value to the next highest value which you don't want when you are doing division.

From your example just doing:

`floor($var3 * 10000) / 10000`

Gave me the correct result and should work properly.

Comment: This clicked me little late. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Use [Round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) - `float round ( float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )`.

You need to pass `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` as 3rd parameter(Mode).

```
round($value, 4, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

If mode parameter is not available in your version of PHP(as it didn't work for me) then use this:

```
floor($value * 10000) / 10000;
```

Comment: `round` will still round up values.  The OP wants to only round down.  `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` takes care of the case for 0.00005 but will round 0.00006 to 0.0001.